# WCF FaultException error "An operations error occured."

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

What does this mean and how do I debug this? Did I set up something wrong on my end? Sorry I'm still trying to wrap my head around WCF.

Message: An Operations error occured.
Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An operations error occurred.
Source Error:

> Line 156:         Line 157:        public
>   WcfWebClientWebApplication.ServiceReference1.SubscriptionEntity[]
>   GetSubscriptions(System.Nullable fromDate,
>   System.Nullable toDate) { Line 158:            return
>   base.Channel.GetSubscriptions(fromDate, toDate); Line 159:        }
>   Line 160:

Stack Trace:

> [FaultException: An operations error occurred. ]
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +14799942
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type) +622
>   WcfWebClientWebApplication.ServiceReference1.IMailSubscription.GetSubscriptions(Nullable`1
>   fromDate, Nullable`1 toDate) +0
>   WcfWebClientWebApplication.ServiceReference1.MailSubscriptionClient.GetSubscriptions(Nullable`1
>   fromDate, Nullable`1 toDate) in
>   d:_myprojects\WcfWebClientWebApplication\WcfWebClientWebApplication\Service
>   References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:158
>   WcfWebClientWebApplication.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e) in
>   d:_myprojects\WcfWebClientWebApplication\WcfWebClientWebApplication\Default.aspx.cs:17
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3178

Code File:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var client = new MailSubscriptionClient();

    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "myUsername";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "myPassword";

    var result = client.GetSubscriptions(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1), DateTime.Today);

    client.Close();
}
```

Web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttp_Username">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://mydomain.com/MailSubscription.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttp_Username"
        contract="ServiceReference1.IMailSubscription" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Is/Are there any Inner Exception(s) in the stack trace? They may help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Put a break point in the web service (server-side) code and go from there.

Comment: I found this error while debugging my client app, **Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority error**. I added this code to trust all certificates and it worked. `Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((send, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);` Is something wrong with the WCF certificate?